# Prove integral function is differentiable

Tags: integration, analysis, derivatives

Consider the function
$$f(x)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln(t)}{1+t^x}dt$$
I want to determine the interval $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ on which the function is well defined and differentiable.

**My attempt:**
So first, I want to verify when the function $t\mapsto \frac{\ln(t)}{1+t^x}$ will be integrable for certain $x$ s.t. $f$ is well defined. Using the fact that $\ln(t)< t$ for all $t>0$ I have in the limit $t\to\infty$ that there will be no obstruction as long as $x>0$. However, I find for the integration limit $t\to0$ that $x<0$. This would mean that $f$ is nowhere well defined? Am I correct?

Comment: Since $\displaystyle \int_0^M\frac{\ln(t)}{1+t}dt \rightarrow \infty$ as $M \rightarrow \infty$, then $x \in I=(1,\infty)$ is a *necessary* condition. One may prove it is *sufficient*.

Comment: Your argument at the $t \rightarrow 0$ end is opaque.  Could you expand on your thinking there?

Comment: @EricTowers I thought the denominator wouldn't matter but that $\ln(t)$ would remain a problem in the limit $t\to 0$? It will be improper integrable?

Comment: Which is larger: $1$ or $1 + (1/2)^3$?  For $t \in (0,1)$, some positive choices of $x$ suppress the magnitude of the integrand.  Is it *enough* suppression?  I don't see your argument resolves this.

Comment: @EricTowers But I should expect that the denominator should become large as we approach $0$ in order to supress the $\ln(t)$  which becomes very large as we approach $0$? If $x$ is positive the denominator will become $1$ in the limit $t\to 0$ so it won't supress the magnitude of $\ln(t)$?

Comment: Are you sure you understand that precisely?  Consider $$\int_0^1 \; \frac{-1}{\sqrt{t}}\,\mathrm{d}t  \text{,}  $$ which integrand also descends to $-\infty$ as $t \rightarrow 0$.  (But this integral converges.  To $-2$.)

Comment: @EricTowers Ow ok you're correct!! The derivative of the integrand can also be dominated for $x\in I=(1,\infty)$ so it will be differentiable for these $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it is worth, here is an explicit expression for $f(x)$ that is valid for all $x > 1$.

Noting that
$$f(x) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\log t}{1 + t^x} \, dt = \frac{d}{ds} \left [\int_0^\infty \frac{t^s}{1 + t^x} \, dt \right ]_{s = 0}.$$
Enforcing a substitution of $t \mapsto t^{\frac{1}{x}}$, for $x > 1$ the integral appearing in the square brackets can be evaluated in terms of a *Beta function*. Here
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \frac{1}{x} \frac{d}{ds} \left [\int_0^\infty  \frac{t^{\frac{s}{x} + \frac{1}{x} - 1}}{1 + t} \, dt \right ]_{s = 0}\\
&= \frac{1}{x} \frac{d}{ds} \left [\operatorname{B} \left (\frac{s}{x} + \frac{1}{x}, 1 - \frac{s}{x} - \frac{1}{x} \right ) \right ]_{s = 0}\\
&= \frac{1}{x} \frac{d}{ds} \left [\Gamma \left (\frac{s}{x} + \frac{1}{x} \right ) \Gamma \left (1 - \frac{s}{x} - \frac{1}{x} \right ) \right ]_{s = 0}\\
&= \frac{1}{x} \frac{d}{ds} \left [\frac{\pi}{\sin \left (\pi \left (\frac{s + 1}{x} \right ) \right )} \right ]_{s = 0}\\
&= \frac{\pi}{x} \frac{d}{ds} \left [\operatorname{cosec} \left (\pi \left (\frac{s + 1}{x} \right ) \right ) \right ]_{s = 0}\\
&= -\frac{\pi^2}{x^2} \cot \left (\frac{\pi}{x} \right ) \operatorname{cosec} \left (\frac{\pi}{x} \right ), \quad x > 1.
\end{align}
Note in the above, the following integral representation for the Beta function has been used:
$$\operatorname{B} (x,y) = \int_0^\infty \frac{t^{x - 1}}{(1 + t)^{x + y}} \, dt, \quad x,y > 0,$$
togther with the well-known *reflexion formula* for the Gamma function $\Gamma (z)$:
$$\Gamma (z) \Gamma (1 - z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin (\pi z)}.$$